# Trigger Click is not working with pickadate.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to trigger the click method but its not working . Please help me to find a solution

```
$( '.New ').live( "click", function() {
    alert("hay");
    $(this).addClass("New1");
    datePick () ;
    jQuery('.New1').trigger('click');
    jQuery('.New1')[0].click();
})
$( '.New1 ').live( "click", function() { 
    datePick () ;
})
function datePick () {
    alert("yes");
    var $input =  $( '.New1' ).pickadate({
       weekdaysShort: [  'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa','Su' ],
       showMonthsShort: true,
       disable: [
           1, 2, 3,4
       ],
       min: [2014,3,20],
       max: [2014,7,14],
       today: false,
       clear:false
       });
     var picker = $input.pickadate('picker'); 
     picker.on('open', function() {
        console.log('Didn’t open.. yet here I am!')
     })
}
```

I am using this to get date http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/index.htm

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on) instead of [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live) like,

```
$( '.New').on( "click", function() {
    alert("hay");
    $(this).addClass("New1");
    datePick () ;
    jQuery('.New1').trigger('click');// using only trigger will work here
})
$( document).on( "click",'.New1', function() { // on for delegation
    datePick () ;
})
function datePick () {
    alert("yes");
    var $input =  $( '.New1' ).pickadate({
       weekdaysShort: [  'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa','Su' ],
       showMonthsShort: true,
       disable: [
           1, 2, 3,4
       ],
       min: [2014,3,20],
       max: [2014,7,14],
       today: false,
       clear:false
       });
     var picker = $input.pickadate('picker'); 
     picker.on('open', function() {
        console.log('Didn’t open.. yet here I am!')
     })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyone referring to this issue in future, `event.stopPropagation();` is the key, as stated in the closed git issue [#481](https://github.com/amsul/pickadate.js/issues/481).

You should use pickadate's `picker.open();` instead of triggering a click. Posting a sample here. [Checkout live sample here.](http://codepen.io/shahabaz/pen/RKjbLy)

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker" />
<button>Click me<br/>to show date picker</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
var $input = $('.datepicker').pickadate();
var picker = $input.pickadate('picker');
picker.on('open', function() {
    console.log('Opened.. and here I am!');
})

$('button').on('click', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    picker.open();
});
```